# How to remove *-pae Grub2 entries from previous install?

Tags: 64-bit, grub2

I recently upgraded Ubuntu 10.10 from 32 to 64bit, but there are two entries I'd like to remove - they're the 32bit entries, with -pae suffix. There is even a initrd-...-pae image for them in /boot. Do you know how  to clean this mess?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than just deleting them (and thus confusing the package manager), *uninstall* the kernels you don't want to show in the GRUB list. Then run `sudo update-grub` to regenerate the list.

Comment: I would, but it won't show in synaptics. I've only got the one I'm running now. Can I delete the old kernels? If so, which files?